# Use OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter in my project?

Tags: spring, jsf, jakarta-ee, entitymanager

due to Lazy loading problems with hibernate I try to set up springs OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.

But I cannot get it to work with my already working app.
What else appart from adding things to web.xml and creating a applicationContext.xml to I have to do, in order to use the Open EM?

Thanks

I have added to web.xml:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>
            OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
        </filter-name>
            <filter-class>
                org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
            </filter-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>flushMode</param-name>
                <param-value>AUTO</param-value>
            </init-param>
    </filter>
    <!-- Include this if you are using Hibernate -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Spring config -->
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

and an applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

</beans>
```

I already can deploy my app, but when I try to launch it throws ex:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an entityManagerFactory into your applicationContext.xml like this:

```
<!-- Add JPA support -->
 <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
    </property>
 </bean>

 <!-- Add Transaction support -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests you do not have a entityManagerFactory defined in your spring config files. Or it is defined with some other name. Try adding this init param to the config in web.xml

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
    <param-value>entityManagerFactory</param-value>
</init-param>
```